# JQuery, would like to update the onClick method of an element. jQuery's click() function isn't working with the syntax I am using

Tags: jquery

Still trying to wrap my head around jQuery, thanks for the help in advance!

Some context for this code. This is a page that allows the user to add questions dynamically, and each question can have associated answers entered in.

My thought process is that in order to generate the answer input boxes within the correct question element I will need to pass the associated questionID to the addAnswer function.

Consequently, I tried to use attr() and update the onClick attribute of the add Answer href but some googling led me to try the click() function.

The behavior I am getting is that whenever addQuestion() is run, it appears that addAnswer() is also run, as I am getting two alerts.

Here's the code.

```
<script>
currentQuestion = 1;

function addQuestion(){      
$('#question0Container').clone().attr('id','question'+currentQuestion).appendTo('#questionArea');
$('addAnswer0').click(addAnswer('0'));
currentQuestion++;
}

function addAnswer(question){
alert(question);
}
</script>

<div id="questionArea">
<div id="question0Container" class="questionContainer">
<textarea id="question0" name="question0"></textarea>
    <div id="answer0Container">
    <h2>Answers</h2>
    <input type="text" id="0-answer1" />
    </div>

    <p><a href="#" id="addAnswer0" class="link-sm">Add Answer</a></p>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#" onClick="addQuestion();" id="addQuestion" title="Add a question" class="link-sm" style="background-color:red;">Add Question</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest would be to supply an [anonymous function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#JavaScript) (sometimes called a lambda expression):

```
$('#addAnswer0').click(function() { addAnswer('0') });
```

The issue is that jQuery event functions take *functions* as arguments. That is, the jQuery library is organized around the concept of [higher-order functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function).  In JavaScript, if you want to **call** a function foo, you write foo(); whereas if you only want to *refer* to a function, to pass it around, you just write foo.  In this case, however, you want to pass an argument, so you want to create a new, anonymous function, which just calls your other function, passing along the argument.

Comment: I did notice people were doing that when googling around. Just gave it a shot and it did take the alert away from when the addQuestion function is run, but it doesn't seem to have binded to the href. BTW, I noticed I forgot the # infront of the selector. I fixed that, still no dice.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Makes sense. Still struggling, I'll post with the html code as well, might help.

Comment: @Bob Jones: I'm not sure what you mean by "binded to the href". The jQuery click event handles clicks (or other UI events that are processed as clicks) -- it doesn't modify the href attribute of the tag or anything like that. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Bob Jones: in response to your edit OD your question: it's a weird style to mix inline event handlers (mixed with your HTML) and programmatically applied event handlers (using jQuery) in the same file. I'd advise you to just use one or the other. That said, there's no need to use an anchor tag with a dummy href just to get a clickable element. In modern browsers, JavaScript can attach event handlers to any DOM element, not just links and buttons.

Comment: Pryden, Ah - perhaps I am barking up the wrong tree then. I just updated the code to include the HTML which will give you more context.

For each generated question div I need to allow the user to create one to many answers for that question. Here's a wireframe of the page which might also help. https://gomockingbird.com/mockingbird/#2ql43kg/0W2gD1

I want to pass the ID of the current question to the addAnswer function so I know which question to add the answer to.

Comment: @Bob Jones: no need to stop at passing the **id** of the element to the other event handler: you can pass the actual element object itself. You'll probably want to use what's called a **closure** -- from inside an anonymous function (or any function) you can reach outside to variables declared in the containing scope. I'd write you an example but I'm on my phone right now... Perhaps I'll do it later or perhaps somebody else will pick up where I left off.

Comment: Closures sound interesting! Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Pryden - I just realized I am not even updating the ID of the text area, rather I have only been updating the ID of the surrounding div tag. 

How would I update the textarea ID of the newly cloned element?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that where you have:

```
$('#addAnswer0').click(addAnswer('0'));
```

you're *calling* the `addAnswer` function, not passing it in as a handler. That's why you get the `addAnwser` alert when you call `addQuestion`. @Daniel's answer should fix this, giving you a function to pass in.

I think we might be missing a little context (e.g. what's the code inside `#question0Container` that you're cloning). When you refer to `#addAnswer0`, is that supposed to be in the new cloned container, or in the `#question0Container`? If it's a button in the new cloned container (which would make sense), shouldn't you be changing the id of the button to use the `currentQuestion` counter?

**Edit**: I have a [working version of this here](http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/b3xSw/3/). Relevant code:

```
var currentQuestion = 1;

function addAnswer() {
   // just look for the parent container
   alert($(this).closest('div').attr('id'));
   return false; // need this to keep the link from
                 // being followed
}

function addQuestion(){      
    var newContainer = $('#question0Container')
      .clone()
      .attr('id','question'+currentQuestion)
      .appendTo('#questionArea');

    $('a.addAnswer', newContainer).click(addAnswer);
    currentQuestion++;
}

// apply it to the existing one too
$(function() {
    $('a.addAnswer').click(addAnswer);
});
```

The main point here is that the better way to use jQuery is not to try manipulating and passing around ids; it's to find things by context (e.g. find the parent container).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just updated the original code sample to include the html - refresh :)

Comment: Thanks much, that's a lot closer! Not sure if you saw this: https://gomockingbird.com/mockingbird/#2ql43kg/0W2gD1 but that is essentially what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Hmm, I'm a little confused at this line, mind stepping through it? Sorry I am a noob.

$('a.addAnswer', newContainer).click(addAnswer);
currentQuestion++;

why are we passing newContainer? I assume the a. vs # syntax is just being more explicit in defining the type of element?

Comment: @Bob - Sorry, didn't have time to comment everything. 1) the `a.addAnswer` syntax is finding the element by css class, rather than id, so you don't have to worry about having multiple elements with the same id. 2) the `$(selector, element)` syntax restricts the search to the element's children - same as `$(element).find(selector)`. That way you're only finding the new Add Answer button, not all of the buttons on the page.